# Render multiple independent redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to render multiple `<User/>` with `<CustomForm/>` they both are stateless component.
But if I try to modify one of the `<CustomForm />` every other `<CustomForm/ >` get also modified, since they all are sharing the same property from the store. How can I have multiple independant `<CustomForm />` ?

```
<User>
    <CustomForm user_id={user_id} />
</User>
<User>
    <CustomForm user_id={user_id}/>
</User>
```

I've connected the form like this:

```
let CustomForm = (props) => {
    const { fields: {author, content}, handleSubmit } = props;

    return (
        <form action="">
            ....
        </form>
    )

}

CustomForm = reduxForm({
  form: `comment`, // I can't access props, i thought something like `comment_${props.user_id}`
  fields: ['author', 'content']
})(CustomForm)

export default CustomForm;
```

Comment: What is `LeaderBoardComments` ?

Comment: Sorry, LeaderBoardComments is the actual name of CustomForm in my project. I have edited my question

Comment: two options. either the store needs to have separate objects to store data for each of those (not optimal). Or you need to introduce state to these components. I would recommend this since individual state of components is supposed to be used in the component itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `formKey`, as it is going away.

Every config parameter passed to `reduxForm()` can be passed as a prop, so you can do

```
<CustomForm form={`comment_${user_id}`}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a `formKey` prop to the component:

```
<CustomForm 
  formKey={user_id.toString()} // needs to be a string.
  user_id={user_id} 
/>
```